# How to mask input on Blackberry browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, blackberry, mobile, maskedinput

I am using a jQuery [`Masked Input`](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin to force the user to type the phone number in proper format.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#PhoneNumber").mask("(999)999-9999");
});
```

The problem I am having is that the [`Masked Input`](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) plugin does not work on blackberry browsers.

I have tried using:

- [iMask](http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/imask/) - no luck
- [Typecast](http://typecast.arapehlivanian.com/index.html) - no luck
- [Masked Input](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) - no luck

Does anyone know how I can get it to work on a blackberry browser.

**I am also welcome to other methods / plugins that would give me similar functionality. (As long as it works on a blackberry browser)**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around, I came accross [**Mask JSAPI library**](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/js/mask/). As it turns out, this does exactly what I needed it to do and it works on a blackberry browser.

So to answer my own question, I ended up using the [**Mask JSAPI library**](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/js/mask/) and used it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.frmReferral.reset();
        oStringMask = new Mask("(###) ###-####");
        oStringMask.attach(document.frmReferral.PhoneNumber);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this: ^\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$ regular expression pattern matches: (999)999-9999
so you could use it to validate the input like this:

$('input:text').val().match(/^\([0-9]{3}\)[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{4}$/);
```

Comment: I need it to function like the demo examples here: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/